# Components in "Visual Studio Code"

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am new "Visual Studio Code" alias VSCode editor.

Is it possible to create Text box,check box like components in VSCode editor?

Answer (score 0):

VSCode does not support custom UI but the [API](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api) does provide a few user input methods. Try looking into `vscode.window.showQuickPick` and `vscode.window.showInputBox`.

I can provider better information if you add more info about what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Thanks @Matt Bierner